# Purpose of Max SDK version in Android

Tags: android, android-manifest

After going through the Android Documentation for Max SDK version i am unclear with effectiveness from 2.1 onward.

Two Statements from Docs :

> 1)
>   Future versions of Android (beyond Android 2.0.1) will no longer check or enforce the 
>   maxSdkVersion attribute during installation or re-validation. Google Play will continue to 
>   use the attribute as a filter, however, when presenting users with applications available for >download.
>
> 2) WARNING:
>
> note that in some cases, declaring the attribute can result in your application being 
>   removed from users' devices after a system update to a higher API Level. Most devices on which your >application is likely to be installed will receive periodic system updates over 
>   the air, so you should consider their effect on your application before setting this attribute.

Can some one make me clear the above two statements.

Reference : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104936/android-min-sdk-version-and-max-sdk-version-setting

Answer (score 2):

After version Android 2.0.1, `maxSdkVersion` will not be used to check and re-validate apk after apk upgrade or system upgrade, however Google play still use this tag to do some filter and present to user according to their device system version. [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) is a more detailed description.

Comment: yes then what about the warning they stated in the link given

Answer (score 1):

The TARGET SDK version serves to acknowledge that the application was verified and tested by the developers for at most that API level.

Of course it can and should work with compatibility mode in new APIs, but it might not.

So it is always important to update to new API levels to assure that it is fully working in those new APIs.

EDIT: The max SDK serves for making the application only run at a maximum SDK and not devices with higher SDK level. It is not recommended because it takes out the possibility of users with higher SDK levels in which the app could run very well in their devices because they are fully backward compatible.

Comment: thanks @tiaga7, i understood that but what about the "WARNING" they stated in Android documentation.

Comment: sorry, I mistook target SDK with max SDK. I have edited my answer. Basically DO NOT declare max SDK, it is pointless and potentially harmful for your application.

Comment: In docs they stated that they are not effective from 2.1 and also in warning they stated that "declaring the attribute can result in your application being removed from users' devices after a system update to a higher API Level." so which is true

Comment: yes, if a user with ICS updates for JB and your app has max SDK ICS, then the app will be uninstalled from that user device when he updates to JB

Comment: but what about the effectiveness from 2.1 .

Comment: Android does not enforce it or checks it onwards 2.0.1. But the google play store will use it to filter applications to users.